# how to move image to mid point of bottom and center of the screen

Tags: android, android-animation

i have class i.e., animatedview.java. this class gives an animation like, image moving from bottom to top and top to bottom.my requirement is i want to move the image from bottom to midpoint of center and bottom like the following screen!

i want to reach this position later i will get down continuously

[image]

mycode is:

public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{

```
static int count=0;
private Context mContext;
int x = 150;
int y = 450;
private float a,b;
private int yVelocity = 20;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 25;
BitmapDrawable ball;
boolean touching;
boolean dm_touched = false;

int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety,bm_w,bm_h;

public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    mContext = context;  
    h = new Handler();

} 
private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(touching = true)
        invalidate(); 
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        //x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = c.getHeight()/2;

    } else {
        y += yVelocity;
        if (y >( this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) ||(y <0)) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }
    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  
  if(touching){
    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
    bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
    bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
  }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchType = event.getAction();

     switch(touchType){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            a = event.getX();
            b = event.getY();
            touching = true;
            break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
             //x and y give you your touch coordinates
              a = event.getX();
              b = event.getY();
              touching = true;
              Log.d("bharat","action_down called");
              if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) {
                  count++;

                   Log.i("bharat",""+count);

                }

                dm_touched = true;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             a = event.getX();
              b = event.getY();
             if(a>x+20&&a<330&&b<=y+320&&b>y)
             invalidate();
            default:

                dm_touched = true;
                touching = true;

            }

            return true;
}
```

}

please help me

Comment: you didn't say what you're getting now. What is the problem? I do see that this: "touching = true" will not work. It's enough to write if(touching)

Comment: thanku barons,thats fine my requirement is i want to move the image bottom to midpoint of center and bottom

Comment: lookup my image, i added now

Comment: What happens now with that code?

Comment: image initially at bottom of the screen,when i click on that image it will move bottom to top and top to bottom

Comment: did u check my answer?

Comment: sorry for late response,ya its working,thanku friend

Comment: small extension of my requirement that is i want to click on that ball once again at that time it has to move center and it goes step by step until ball reach to top of the screen,can u give an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly this should fix it:
instead of y< 0, you should put y < c.getHeight()/2

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
if (x<0 && y <0) {
    //x = this.getWidth()/2;
    y = c.getHeight()/2;

} else {
    y += yVelocity;
    if (y >( this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) ||(y <c.getHeight()/2)) {
        yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
    }
}
c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  
if(touching){
h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
}
}
```

Comment: If it helps, I'd appreciate it if you would accept the answer. Thanks! regarding the next question, u need to add a counter to case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP then check if it was clicked more than once, and in onDraw check if you need to go up, run the same loop with y < 0

Comment: sorry for bad English,actually my question is when i click first time it moves to certain distance as u said y<c.getHeight its fine,if image touch the bottom then game over for that iwant to click on that ball again and again,finally my target is the image should not touch the top and bottom borders,if touch means game over,like that i am thinking

Comment: u said that "onDraw check if you need to go up" but how can i go up every time when i click on image until it reach the top